# Menu list links of different languages of a Localized Menu are shown in all languages?

Tags: 7, routes, i18n-l10n

I have a menu which is set to **Translate and Localize. Menu items with language will allow translations. Menu items without language will be localized.**

The in the menu I have several links in english and spanish languages.

In the frontend regardless the language I select all links of the menu are shown. ie: if I select english the spanish links are also shown.

What am I missing here?

Comment: version D7 or D6?

Comment: it is version D7

Comment: check your translate configuration page. it might be listing in both languages.

Comment: not sure which page do you mean. If you mean `admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu/translate` the menu is not translated to english, just Spanish source is active.

Comment: No, i mean `admin/config/regional/translate/translate` at this page. try to filter

Comment: are you using `118n` or `entity translate` module?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you already have the **[i18n Menu Translation](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/i18n/tree/i18nmenu)** sub-module is enabled (it is one of the [Internationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) sub-modules).

Edit the menu to be translated, by navigating to admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu/edit (for the "main menu"). From there you can select the **translation mode** you want, e.g. *Translate and Localize* (from your question it seems you also did that already).

With what's above you should be in pretty good shape to complete the finishing touch: when editing a menu link, there should be a new link **Translate** to actually translate the menu entry. After you entered a translation for the "original" (eg English) menu item in another language (eg Spanish), Drupal will ensure that whenever you switch to another language, the corresponding menu item will be switched also (to the matching language).

Should you have some other menu item in your original menu in that "other" language, you can safely delete that menu item. After you delete such item, that'll be 1 menu item less that is shown "in both languages" (as in your question). Repeat the above (= translate menu item and delete original duplicate item) for each of your duplicate (in both languages) menu items.

Refer to the [Multilingual Guide](https://www.drupal.org/node/1113982) for (way) more details.

Miltilingual sites are really fun in D7 (way better then it was in D6, and D8 promises to become more easy to configure). Typical variations (with similar solutions) of this "menu" topic are:

- **translations of blocks**, which requires the Block Languages (i18n_block) submodule to be enabled.
- **translations of taxonomies**, which requires the Taxonomy Translation (i18n_taxonomy) submodule to be enabled.